# Third Order Differential Equation using the reduction of order method.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation
$y'''-2y''+y'-2y=0$ $(1)$ using the reduction of order method and also by
replacing $y$ with $z=z(x)=y'-2y$ $(2)$
So $z'=y''-2y'$$(3)$,$z''=y'''-2y''$$(4)$
therefore (1) becomes $z''+z=0$ and we can easily find the general solution.
So my question is... what about the function $z'=y''-2y'$
We can not plug that in $(1)$ because the function $z''=y'''-2y''$ is the first two terms of the original differential equation and the function $z=y'-2y$ is that last two terms.

Comment: You only need $z'$ as an intermediate result to get $z''$, there is no need to substitute it back into the original equation

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, $$y'''-2y''+y'-2y=(\underbrace{y''-2y'}_{z'})'+\underbrace{y'-2y}_{z}=0,$$ so $z''+z=0.$ So $z=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t),$ and then you can use the assignment $z = y'-2y$ to see you need only solve $y'-2y = c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t).$
The solutions to $z=y'-2y$ provides the solutions to $z'=y''-2y',$ so we don't need to put any extra effort there.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you like the answer, please consider upvoting, and clicking the green check mark to accept the answer  I'm glad it helped!